# Do call to android.os.Looper.loop() require android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED to be specified in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, security

At work, we run our apps through a security scan tool that does static analysis for vulnerabilities.  Sometimes it flags things that aren't security related but could cause problems in some other way.  In this case, it's complaining about [Improper Handling of Insufficient Privileges](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/274.html).

Here's the description from the tool:

> This application calls the android.os.Looper.loop() API, which
>   requires the following permission(s) that are not specified in
>   AndroidManifest.xml: android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED.  These
>   calls will not be executed.  Depending on implementation, this
>   condition may result in an error message, or the code will fail
>   silently.  Underpermission conditions are not exploitable flaws, but
>   they may indicate the presence of unexpected code (e.g. an advertising
>   library attempting to leak the user's GPS location).

However, The [API docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) make no mention of the `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` value or the `AndroidManifest.xml` file at all.

Is `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` really required by the [Looper.loop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#loop%28%29) call, or is this a false positive?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be required. `Looper.loop` is called by essentially every Android program, whether behind the scenes or overtly. I can't see why they would require a permission to use it. It is required to show even the simplest of graphics... I'm sure this is a false positive in the tool you used.

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

It's been around since API level 1. Shouldn't be too complicated to fix.

Comment: The OP is asking if the `Looper` actually needs the above permission, not what the permission is/does.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to actually "answer" the question.

Comment: He should just be able to set the permission in his .xml file. Eclipse is often very odd about the XML file and in order for the OP to get it to work he/she may have to clean and recompile a few times. If this permission is what he/she is complaining about, it should be as simple as define, save, clean, compile, run.

Comment: Judging on the fact that their program is complaining about this permission, I'd say that they would need to define it and it really shouldn't be that big of an issue to deal with. It's just a permission. It may not necessarily be just the Looper class that needs this too. It could be something on the stack that needs it anyways. Just define it and try again. No sense in not trying.